# Laravel-8 , Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\table()

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

While running this command `php artisan db:seed` I get this error: "Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\table()"
Screen shot:
[error in db seeding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnT6s.png)

As I am new to laravel , I coundn't fix the bug of my code after searching for various examples.I created a model by `php artisan make:model ServiceCategory -m` command which created this model ServiceCategory.php :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ServiceCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

and also created a migration 2022_07_20_200919_create_service_categories_table.php file :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('service_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->index();
            $table->string('image'); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('service_categories');
    }
};
```

Then I created a seeder name : ServiceCategorySeeder.php :

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ServiceCategorySeeder extends Seeder
{
    
    public function run()
    {
        DB:table('service_categories')->insert([
            [
                "name"=> "AC Installation",
                "slug"=>"ac-installation",
                "image"=>"ac installation.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "AC Uninstallation",
                "slug"=>"ac-uninstallation",
                "image"=>"ac uninstallation.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "AC Repair",
                "slug"=>"ac-repair",
                "image"=>"ac repair.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Laundry",
                "slug"=>"laundry",
                "image"=>"laundry.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Electrical",
                "slug"=>"electrical",
                "image"=>"electrical.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Plumbing",
                "slug"=>"plumbing",
                "image"=>"plumbing.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Painting",
                "slug"=>"painting",
                "image"=>"painting.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "House Shifitng",
                "slug"=>"house shifitng",
                "image"=>"house-shifitng.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Tank Cleaning",
                "slug"=>"tank cleaning",
                "image"=>"tank-cleaning.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Furniture",
                "slug"=>"furniture",
                "image"=>"furniture.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Home Deep Cleaning",
                "slug"=>"home-deep-cleaning",
                "image"=>"home deep cleaning.png"
            ],
            [
                "name"=> "Bathroom Deep Cleaning",
                "slug"=>"bathroom-deep-cleaning",
                "image"=>"bathroom deep cleaning.png"
            ]
            
            ]);
    }
}
```

also modified DatabaseSeeder.php is:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            ServiceCategorySeeder::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

The successfully running the command : `composer dump-autoload` I ran the command `php artisan db:seed` which lead the this error is ss:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnT6s.png)

```
ABIR HASSAN@LAPTOP-D9T7UM30 MINGW64 /d/XAMP/htdocs/testproject_Copy
$ php artisan db:seed
Seeding: Database\Seeders\ServiceCategorySeeder

   Error

  Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\table()

  at D:\XAMP\htdocs\testproject_Copy\database\seeders\ServiceCategorySeeder.php:13
      9▕ {
     10▕
     11▕     public function run()
     12▕     {
  ➜  13▕         DB:table('service_categories')->insert([
     14▕             [
     15▕                 "name"=> "AC Installation",
     16▕                 "slug"=>"ac-installation",
     17▕                 "image"=>"ac installation.png"

  1   D:\XAMP\htdocs\testproject_Copy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Database\Seeders\ServiceCategorySeeder::run()

  2   D:\XAMP\htdocs\testproject_Copy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
```

Thank you advance for your help.

Comment: Static methods, like the `DB` facade's [`table` method](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.html#method_table) are called using `::`, not `:`. Fix that typo and you should be good 

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I did use `DB::table` instead of `DB:table` and got a new error. ` Error Class "Database\Seeders\DB" not found at D:\XAMP\htdocs\testproject_Copy\database\seeders\ServiceCategorySeeder.php:13 `

Comment: You need to add `use DB;` (or  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`; I forget which) at the top of your file. That's how namespaces work; if you try to use a Class `DB` without importing it, it looks in the current namespace. `DB` doesn't exist in the `Database\Seeders` namespace.

Comment: Excellent! Watch your typing in the future, and if possible, use some kind of IDE or Application (like PHPStorm, VSCode, etc.) that can highlight and catch these syntax errors; it'll help you in the long run. Cheers 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your seeder, you need `DB::table` instead of `DB:table`

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I did use `DB::table` instead of `DB:table` and got a new error.

  ` Error 

  Class "Database\Seeders\DB" not found

  at D:\XAMP\htdocs\testproject_Copy\database\seeders\ServiceCategorySeeder.php:13 `

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` on the top of your seeder